# How do I use a logger in a script used in data-sly-use in AEM?

Tags: aem, aem-6

Data sly use is used for helper classes this could either be a Java WCMUsePojo or a server side Javascript .

How do I use a logger in a server side script eg. data-sly-use.nav="nav.js" ?

Comment: Does the default log object not work for your case? You can access it in server side JS using: ${log.info("some info")}

Comment: @i.net Never tried. Using these Java objects in Javascript is really weird.

Comment: I've added more details in the answer with reference to docs if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTL comes with a set of global objects that are ready to be used in server side JS. One of these objects is the `log` object which exposes an implementation of `org.slf4j.Logger`

You can use it like the example below in your code:

```
log.info("some info");
```

More details can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/htl/docs/global-objects.html) which also details out a lot of other helpful objects available in the same context.

Comment: Ok, can you improve the answer on how you got it to work (also maybe add AEM version as 6.2 and 6.3 differ in usage of these objects) so that it benefits everyone (including me).

Comment: It worked for me this way in my server side script  instead of ${log.info("some info")} so I edited the answer.